# Insert into select from clause causes 'cannot insert multiple rows error'

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert

I am using `insert into select from` clause to insert data to the table, but it doesn't work.

Please see here:

```
insert into STAGES_ROLES_REL
              select 
                  (select stage_id 
                   from
                  (select ws2.workflow_stage_id as stage_id
                         from
                        ( select ws.workflow_stage_name as workflow_stage_name
                          from   workflow_stages ws
                          join   stages_roles_rel sr
                            on   ws.workflow_stage_id = sr.workflow_stage_id ) table1
                  join workflow_stages ws2    
                  on   table1.workflow_stage_name =  ws2.workflow_stage_name
                  order by ws2.workflow_stage_id))
             ,role_id
             ,current_date created_date, user created_by
             ,null modified_date, null modified_by
              from stages_roles_rel
```

The error is cannot insert multiple rows, but I don't know how to put filter and fetch individual row.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Your error is most likely that a subquery cannot return more than on erow, because you have scalar subqueries with not control over the number of rows being returned.

Comment: Yes, I know it returns multiple rows, but how to fetch the row one by one... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this query is returning multiple results:

```
select stage_id
    from (
      select ws2.workflow_stage_id as stage_id
      from (
        select ws.workflow_stage_name as workflow_stage_name
        from workflow_stages AS ws
        inner join stages_roles_rel AS sr
          on ws.workflow_stage_id = sr.workflow_stage_id
        ) AS table1
      inner join workflow_stages ws2    
      on table1.workflow_stage_name =  ws2.workflow_stage_name
      order by ws2.workflow_stage_id
    )
```

If that's what you want (multiple rows out of that query), move your constants into that query and get rid of the outer query:

```
insert into STAGES_ROLES_REL
select
  stage_id,
  role_id,
  current_date AS created_date,
  user AS created_by,
  null AS modified_date,
  null AS modified_by
from (
  select ws2.workflow_stage_id as stage_id
  from (
    select ws.workflow_stage_name as workflow_stage_name
    from workflow_stages AS ws
    inner join stages_roles_rel AS sr
      on ws.workflow_stage_id = sr.workflow_stage_id
    ) AS table1
  inner join workflow_stages ws2    
  on table1.workflow_stage_name =  ws2.workflow_stage_name
  order by ws2.workflow_stage_id
    )
   [add a cross join to the original table if that's what you're wanting, I don't know the intent of your original query]
```

Otherwise, you'll need to fix your query to only return one row.